# Intel SSD setting all files to read only

Tags: ssd

I've been using my Intel 525 SSD for a few months as my primary hard drive and have not had any problems. One day none of my programs on my Windows 7 I installed would run. When I ran them a blank window would open and it would idle forever. According to palimpsest running on a Linux live cd there were no problems with the drive.

I installed Windows 8.1 and had a working installation for a few hours. After installing many programs, I installed the JDK. During installation the installer froze and I noticed after I killed the process I was having the same problems before.

The issue seems to be that my SSD will mark files randomly as read-only. If I unmark them as read only and reboot they are marked as read-only again. I've ran Intel SSD Toolbox which says that my firmware is up to date. I also ran a quick diagnostic check which also said the drive is fine.

Questions:

- Has anyone else ran into this problem of an SSD marking files as read only? If so, is there any fix? Should I throw out the drive?
- I've heard that when installing an operating system onto an SSD, no other drives should be connected. Is there any truth to this? When I installed Windows I had a regular hard drive also connected as a data drive

Comment: "The issue seems to be that my SSD will mark files randomly as read-only", are you talking about _files_ or _folders_? Windows always (re)marks Folders as read-only, it's supposed to be that way.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/131119/folder-keeps-changing-back-to-read-only-what-permissions-setup-causes-this-in-w

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm referring to folders. Yes, the marking is in a grayed out state (not a full check)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 What originally lead my to this assumption was on the first boot of windows not working, dropbox errored. I unchecked read-only on the dropbox folder and it worked again. Could it be that other files and folders not intended as read-only are being marked incorrectly?